# Connecting scrcpy (a android phone screen mirroring software) to my Windows Virtual Private Server?. Is it possible and how?

Tags: windows, adb, vps

Could someone please demonstrate the procedure for connecting scrcpy (a android phone screen mirroring software) to my Windows Virtual Private Server?. Or at least point me in some direction so I know how to solve it myself

I have attempted to do it independently; however, the process appears rather intricate and challenging to grasp.

The documentation I have unsuccessfully followed can be found at the following link: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/blob/master/doc/tunnels.md.

Comment: scrcpy only work for Android as target, Windows is not supported.

Comment: I don't understand? I used scrcpy on Windows. How is not supported?

Comment: Windows is only supported as the host, not as the client from which you mirror the screen. I can only interpret your question this way that you want to remote control a Windows instance in the cloud. If this is not the case may be consider improving your question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Thank you, you understood my question well. Is there some way, some program that will allow a USB connection from my computer to my VPS or maybe some program that will allow me to show my phone screen to the VPS without AirDroid